# How to assigning a class to quicksand data filtered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, filtering, quicksand

I found this answer when I was searching for [linking to quicksand prefiltered page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491313/jquery-quicksand-linking-to-prefiltered-page) and I made some editing on the code to make my urls more friendly, data filtered in 4 columns and I want to assign a specific class for the items of column #1 and another class to the items of column #4, all the code if run well except the part of assigning classes to the filtered data.
Please help me, I will really appreciate your effort.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// get the action filter option item on page load
var $filterType = $('#sidebar .filter a.active').attr('data-value');

// get and assign the ourHolder element to the
// $holder varible for use later
var $holder = $('.filter-container');

// clone all items within the pre-assigned $holder element
var $data = $holder.clone();

var $button = $('#sidebar .filter a');

var $all = $('.filter-container .part').data('type') === 'all';

// reset the active class on all the buttons
$button.removeClass('active');

// assign the class of the clicked filter option
// element to our $filterType variable
var $filtered = 'greases';

$('a[data-value=' + $filtered + ']').addClass('active dark');

var $filteredData = $data.find('.part[data-type~=' + $filtered + ']').show();

    // Assigning the classes    
$filteredData.removeClass('alpha omega').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 4 == 0) $(this).addClass('alpha');
    if (index % 4 == 3) $(this).addClass('omega');
});

    // call quicksand and assign transition parameters
$holder.quicksand($filteredData, {
    duration: 750,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
});
});
```

Comment: يا أهلا بيك .. أخيراً حد عبّرنى :)